# Product of $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ on circle

Tags: combinatorics

We have $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n$ arranged in a circle, where $n\geq 3$.

Every $x_i$ belongs to $\{1,−1\}$.

We can choose arbitrarily $3$ consequent numbers and know their product.

> What is the minimum number of questions to know the product of the entire circle?

Comment: wouldn't it just be $\text{ceil}(n/3)$ ?

Comment: To address my prior comment, it is *not* $\text{ceil}(n/3)$ unless 3 divides $n$.

Comment: So each value is 1 or -1?

Comment: yes each value 1 or -1

Comment: for n = 3k it is clear